# Cross-env can't find module '..'

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am using gulp to copy created build package:

```
gulp.task('fill-deploy-target', ['init-deploy-target'], () =>
gulp.src(['server*/**/*', 'node_modules*/**/*', 'package.json', 'package-lock.json',
    'ecosystem.config.js', 'gulpfile.js', '.sequelizerc'], { dot: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${deployTargetDir}/app_install/app/package`)));
```

In node_modules there is a folder .bin that is causing the problem. All files in the .bin folder are copied but when I try to run build cross-env is giving me this error. When I copy .bin folder manually to the server there are no error regards that it is the same folder with same files. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could it be a permission issue? The execution flag missing on bin/ files copied through gulp?

Comment: It's not permission, the problem is when gulp copy it changes the file type

Answer (score 8):

I'm not using gulp, but my guess is that gulp does not honor (soft) symlinks.

In my .bin folder all files are symlinks into node_modules folders:
[image]

However, when I just copy the folder (e.g. with filezilla, or in your case with gulp), I see following (`ls -al`):

[image]

When you inspect the `cross-env` file, you can see that it requires ('..') file, which works in case of symlink, however fails if it just copied the file.

```
$ cat cross-env

#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

var crossEnv = require('..');

crossEnv(process.argv.slice(2));
```

So solution is to copy .bin files with symlinks or run cross-env with absolute path like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run production",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node your-app.js",
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node your-app.js"
  },
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been zipping and extracting my node_modules in CI and got this error. Adding `--symlinks` to the `zip` command fixed it.